# Dynamically load a stylesheet with React

Tags: javascript, stylesheet, reactjs, isomorphic-javascript

I'm building a CMS system for managing marketing landing pages. On the "Edit Landing Page" view, I want to be able to load the associated stylesheet for whichever landing page the user is editing. How could I do something like this with React?

My app is fully React, isomorphic, running on [Koa](http://koajs.com/). My basic component heirarchy for the page in question looks something like this:

```
App.jsx (has `<head>` tag)
└── Layout.jsx (dictates page structure, sidebars, etc.)
    └── EditLandingPage.jsx (shows the landing page in edit mode)
```

Data for the landing page (including the path of the stylesheet to load) is fetched asynchronously in `EditLandingPage` in `ComponentDidMount`.

Let me know if you need any additional info. Would love to get this figured out!

Bonus: I'd also like to unload the stylesheet when navigating away from the page, which I assume I can do the reverse of whatever answer comes my way in `ComponentWillUnmount`, right?

Answer (score 40):

Just update stylesheet's path that you want to be dynamically loaded by using react's state.

```
import * as React from 'react';

export default class MainPage extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {stylePath: 'style1.css'};
    }

    handleButtonClick(){
        this.setState({stylePath: 'style2.css'});
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href={this.state.stylePath} />
                <button type="button" onClick={this.handleButtonClick.bind(this)}>Click to update stylesheet</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
};
```

Also, I have implemented it as react component. You can install via npm install react-dynamic-style-loader. 
Check my github repository to examine:
 https://github.com/burakhanalkan/react-dynamic-style-loader

Comment: I didn't want to load a whole stylesheet especially since I'm using Rails, so I did this bit of hackery based on your answer but adding a style tag conditionally https://gist.github.com/siakaramalegos/eafd1b114ddcbe8fac923edbc9f8a553

Comment: this worked nicely for what i need. Im using react-create-app so i had to move the css to the public folder.

Comment: @cabaji99 What does your href look like for your link element? Did you do `"%PUBLIC_URL%/stylesheet_name.css"` or what?

Comment: This worked nicely for me too, remember that if you want to dynamically access stylesheets that are situated in your `public` folder from within your Javascript code you should use the `PUBLIC_URL` environment variable as follows:

`<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href={ process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/foo.css' }/>`

Comment: What if you want to put it in the `<head>` tag?

Comment: @MarcoPrins You can try react-helmet to render into the `<head>` element

Comment: seems to work on load, but not when state changes later. i.e. reloading the style

Comment: @ShahriyarImanov it's valid. As long as the link tag has 'body ok' type, it can be used in the body. Please check usage notes in here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link

Comment: @burakhanalkan : which is quite discouraged practice.

Comment: @ShahriyarImanov that's true. Although it's not the best practice, it's still valid markup.

Comment: how can I load css to style tag from package, bootstrap for example? before I used `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';`

Answer (score 19):

I think that Burakhan answer is correct but it is weird to load `<Link href = "" />` inside the body tag. That's why I think it should be modified to the following [ I use React hooks]:

```
import * as React from 'react';
export default MainPage = (props) => {
  const [ stylePath, setStylePath ] = useState("style1.css");
    
  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    setStylePath({stylePath: 'style2.css'});
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    var head = document.head;
    var link = document.createElement("link");

    link.type = "text/css";
    link.rel = "stylesheet";
    link.href = stylePath;

    head.appendChild(link);

    return () => { head.removeChild(link); }

  }, [stylePath]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button type="button" onClick={handleButtonClick}>
        Click to update stylesheet
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I think you'd need a `return () => { head.removeChild(link); }` just under the `head.appendChild` node to clean up, else you'll just keep adding nodes when the stylePath will change.

Answer (score 8):

This is prime mixin teritority.  First we'll define a helper to manage style sheets.

We need a function that loads a style sheet, and returns a promise for its success.  Style sheets are actually pretty insane to detect load on...

```
function loadStyleSheet(url){
  var sheet = document.createElement('link');
  sheet.rel = 'stylesheet';
  sheet.href = url;
  sheet.type = 'text/css';
  document.head.appendChild(sheet);
  var _timer;

  // TODO: handle failure
  return new Promise(function(resolve){
    sheet.onload = resolve;
    sheet.addEventListener('load', resolve);
    sheet.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if (sheet.readyState === 'loaded' || sheet.readyState === 'complete') {
        resolve();
      }
    };

    _timer = setInterval(function(){
      try {
        for (var i=0; i<document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
          if (document.styleSheets[i].href === sheet.href) resolve();
        } catch(e) { /* the stylesheet wasn't loaded */ }
      }
    }, 250);
  })
  .then(function(){ clearInterval(_timer); return link; });
}
```

Well $#!@... I was expecting to just stick an onload on it, but nope.  This is untested, so please update it if there are any bugs – it's compiled from several blog articles.

The rest is fairly straight forward:

- allow loading a stylesheet
- update state when it's available (to prevent FOUC)
- unload any loaded stylesheets when the component unmounts
- handle all the async goodness

```
var mixin = {
  componentWillMount: function(){
    this._stylesheetPromises = [];
  },
  loadStyleSheet: function(name, url){
    this._stylesheetPromises.push(loadStyleSheet(url))
    .then(function(link){
      var update = {};
      update[name] = true;
      this.setState(update);
    }.bind(this));
  },
  componentWillUnmount: function(){
    this._stylesheetPromises.forEach(function(p){
      // we use the promises because unmount before the download finishes is possible
      p.then(function(link){
        // guard against it being otherwise removed
        if (link.parentNode) link.parentNode.removeChild(link);
      });
    });
  }
};
```

Again, untested, please update this if there are any issues.

Now we have the component.

```
React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return {foo: false};
  },
  componentDidMount: function(){
    this.loadStyleSheet('foo', '/css/views/foo.css');
  },
  render: function(){
    if (!this.state.foo) {
      return <div />
    }

    // return conent that depends on styles
  }
});
```

The only remaining todo is checking if the style sheet already exists before trying to load it.  Hopefully this at least gets you on the right path.

Comment: Wow, awesome! I'll definitely give this a shot and let ya know how it works out. Thanks!

Comment: Focus testing on firefox, because it has the worst support of all browsers.

Comment: this is helpful, but there are some typos(bugs)

Comment: I don't understand why one wouldn't just change the href attribute of a link inside of your project based on a prop or state...

Answer (score 3):

I use react-helmet, in render function....

```
{inject ? 
    <Helmet>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    </Helmet> : null}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I add style dynamically:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class MyComponent extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        const cssUrl = "/public/assets/css/style.css";
        this.addStyle(cssUrl);
    }

    addStyle = url => {
        const style = document.createElement("link");
        style.href = url;
        style.rel = "stylesheet";
        style.async = true;

        document.head.appendChild(style);
    };

    render() {
        return <div> textInComponent </div>;
    }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: What about bundling, minification and cache busting?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet

Install react-helmet and use it for dynamic css for separate components. Example is
For 1st component, using style1.css

```html
<>
     <Helmet>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style1.css" />
     </Helmet>
     ...
</>
```

For 2nd component, using style2.css

```html
<>
     <Helmet>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style1.css" />
     </Helmet>
     ...
</>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating elements for stylesheet, you can also try importing your css based on some condition. ECMAScript provides a proposal that enables dynamic module imports, that works as follows:

```
if (condition) {
  import('your css path here').then((condition) => {});
}
```

Comment: importing does not help when you are switching themes, we will have CSS overlap.

Answer (score 0):

On my approach i use this:

```
const TenantSelector = ({ children }) => {
  // imagine its value from a json config
  const config = {
      custom_style: 'css/tenant.css' 
  }
  require(`./assets/${config.custom_style}`)
  return (
    <>
      <React.Suspense fallback={<></>}>
      </React.Suspense>
      {children}
    </>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <TenantSelector>
   <YourApp>
  </TenantSelector>,
  document.getElementById("root")
)
```

Comment: Please add some comments about your code, what it does and how does it answers the question.