# Switch between two external css files in react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to apply an option where user can switch between dark mode and light mode in the application.

```
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/cssf/light.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/cssf/dark.css">
```

I have two sheets for the whole website.

```
<label class="form-check-label" id="dark">
                            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" checked name="theme"><label>Dark</label>
                          </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check-inline">
                          <label class="form-check-label" id="light">
                            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="theme"><label>Light</label>
                          </label>
```

I have given the option but what do i have to do to switch between the two css files?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./cssf/style.css";
import logo from "./cssf/logo-sm.png";

function App() {

  const [ stylePath, setStylePath ] = useState("./cssf/dark-theme.css");
    
  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    setStylePath("./cssf/light-theme.css");
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    var head = document.head;
    var link = document.createElement("link");

    link.type = "text/css";
    link.rel = "stylesheet";
    link.href = stylePath;

    head.appendChild(link);

    return () => { head.removeChild(link); }

  }, [stylePath]);
```

I used this method and it is updating the link tag perfectly in the head but without importing it to my app using import "../cssf/sheername.css" it is of no use.How can i solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that’s quite an interesting issue.

For dynamically importing css files into react I’d check this thread: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28386125/dynamically-load-a-stylesheet-with-react)

However I don’t think this is the best solution, as it is potentially very hard to maintain and not very DRY.

I would rather have 1 css file that looks at the class on body and changes css colors based on that (assuming you don’t change layout, only colors)

Comment: Yeah even i think this is not the best solution.Its just the client provided me with these two css files and asked to apply a toggle option.I dont know what to do

Comment: Ah ok, fair enough. I think the link I provided should definitely point you in the correct direction. :)