# Adding CSS in React file

Tags: css, reactjs

How do I add specific CSS file which I have in a variable?

```
render {

 const {styleSheet} = this.prop;

 return (
    <div className={styleSheet}>
       <h4> Hi </h4>
    <div>
 )
}
```

Let say I have that stylesheet prop can have values as `red` , `green` and `blue`

- `red` for font colour red and content in left.
- `green` for font colour green and content in center.
- `blue` for font colour blue and content in right.

How I can create diffrent style sheet files for each value?

ps. i am trying to create something in which i will have template... template will have lots of same data but with diffrent styling...as an example if we take a report card...each report card have same data but it have diffrent tempates.....so i want to create diffrent stylesheets for diffrent templates...now please answer.

Comment: Can you show log of what styleSheet contains??

Comment: Maybe this link will be helpful: `Four ways to style react components` https://codeburst.io/4-four-ways-to-style-react-components-ac6f323da822

Comment: i have updated the post please go through it again.

Comment: so what you want is to add a different css file to every component instance?

Comment: yes the templateStyle will decide styling for each component, it will be diffrent in each style sheet value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have able to add css like this..

```
useEffect(() => {
    var head = document.head;
    var link = document.createElement("link");

    link.type = "text/css";
    link.rel = "stylesheet";
    link.href = process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "./styles/templates/" + templateStyle;

    head.appendChild(link);

    return () => { head.removeChild(link); }

}, [templateStyle]);
```

via this i can add css files dynamicaly.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you simply have rules matching each className in your CSS ?
Like :

```
.red {
 color: #ff0000;
 text-align: left;
}
```

And so on ?

Comment: i am trying to create something in which i will have template...easy template will have lots of same data but with diffrent styling...as an example if we take a report card...each report card have same data but it have diffrent tempates.....so i want to create diffrent stylesheets for diffrent templates...now please answer.

Comment: Look at this post it seems to be what you're looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28386125/dynamically-load-a-stylesheet-with-react

Answer (score 0):

You can import that CSS file as a CSS Module in the file where you have define your component.

You can learn more about **[CSS Module Stylesheet](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/)**

just a simple example you can have a `HelloWorld` Component which have a stylesheet file which is scoped to it like this.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
// Here you import the CSS MODULE
import classes from './HelloWord.css';

class HelloWord extends Component {
    render() {
        return <div className={classes.HelloWord}>
            <h2 className={classes.red}>Hello World</h2>
        </div>
    }
}
```

and in the `HelloWord.module.css` you can define any css classes as you'll like\

```
.HelloWorld {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.red {
    color: red;
}
// and so on
```

As you can see all classes which I have define in the `HelloWorld.module.css` file are available in the `classes` variable, with that It's up to you to decide which CSS class selector you want to apply to element in your JSX

Comment: please read the post i have updated it ..so you can understand what exactly i'm askingg?