# React: Dynamic import css

Tags: reactjs, react-lazy-load

I am new to react. I want to import either "darkMode.css" or "lightMode.css" (to a class-based component) based on the value of `props`.

Imagine I have the below function (in the class based component):

```
cssName = () => (this.props.mode === "dark"? "darkMode.css":"lightMode.css")
```

Is there a way to import "darkMode.css" or "lightMode.css" using this function?

Thank you for helping!

Comment: Duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34837201/5605822

Answer (score 0):

```
cssName = () => {
  if (this.props.mode === 'dark') {
    return import('darkmode.css').then((module) => 
      // whatever you want to do with module
    );
  }

  return import('lightMode.css').then((module) =>
    // whatever you want to do with module
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! But if props.mode changes, cssName() will be called multiple times, and there will be two css files imported. How do I remove the wrong import?

Comment: @YigeSong You can't(it's possible but I don't recommend it).